# $_SESSION login script: not validating users in SQL database

Tags: php, validation, session, mysqli, authentication

My database setup is like so:

```
create database if not exists shop;
use shop;
create table if not exists users(
 id serial primary key,
 username varchar(20),
 password char(20));    

create table if not exists admins(
 id serial primary key,
 username varchar(20),
 password char(20));

insert into admins values(null, 'admin', SHA('touch'));
```

and my main problem exists with the login_process page.

```
<?php
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","shop")or die(mysqli_error($db));
 $q="select * from admins where username='$username' and password=SHA('$password')";
 $results=mysqli_query($db, $q)or die(mysqli_error($db));
 if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0)
 {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username']=$username;
  header("Location:index.php");
  exit(0);
 }
 else
 {
   header("Location:login.php");
   exit(0);
 }
?>
```

When the page tries to validate my admin, instead of the location heading to index.php, it instead stays on login.php and the admin credentials never validate. The same problem persists in my login and register process pages with their respective roles.

Comment: Your code is open to SQL-Injection!

Comment: What is SQL-Injection?

Comment: Sometimes you have to know when you need to use google

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's SHA function return 40 hex digits string. The password field need to handle 40 characters to make SHA works.

Answer (score -1):

Address the issues by following

type session_start on the login page & declare $_SESSION variables as ''

`$q="select * from admins where username='$username' and password=SHA('$password')";`
`echo` this query & run on backend,see if it returns data?

So if the above query returns data then sure redirection will be on index page

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm a bit confused. Is the $_SESSION variable this?
"$_SESSION['username']=$username;" Should I put the $q statement in the square brackets?